# PHP array format

Tags: php, json

How can I get this format:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "id":            4,
        "link":          "/product.php?id_product=4",
        "quantity":      1,
        "priceByLine":   "$185.00",
        "name":          "Orci hendrer...",
        "price":         "$185.00",
        "idCombination": 0,
        "hasAttributes": false,
        "hasCustomizedDatas": false,

        "customizedDatas":[
                ]


    },  {
        "id":            5,
        "link":          "/product.php?id_product=5",
        "quantity":      1,
        "priceByLine":   "$215.00",
        "name":          "Semper rutru...",
        "price":         "$215.00",
        "idCombination": 0,
        "hasAttributes": false,
        "hasCustomizedDatas": false,

        "customizedDatas":[
                ]


    }],

}
```

as a PHP array? I've tried

```
$array[] = array('id'=>5, link => 'product.php?id_product=5' ... and so on)
```

but when I encode with JSON it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to nest your arrays in the proper way like the following example.

```
$arr = array( 'products' => array(
  array('id'=>4, link => 'product.php?id_product=4' ),
  array('id'=>5, link => 'product.php?id_product=5' )
  )
);
```

**EDIT**

In your code it would look like this to init the object:

```
$arr = array( 'products' => array() );
```

And each subsequent product could be added like this (e.g., in a loop where you parse your database result):

```
$arr['products'][] = array('id'=>5, link => 'product.php?id_product=5' );
```

Comment: ok i've tryed that and it works but how to get to that result, i have an ajax call that goes to a controller in the controller i need to encode that code it's very simple but the question is should i do it in a foreach loop? i mean how to make that multidimensional array . Each time i add a new product that products array should be like '$arr = array( 'products' => array(
  array('id'=>4, link => 'product.php?id_product=4' ),
  array('id'=>5, link => 'product.php?id_product=5' )
  )
);
'

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
  'products' => array(
    array('id'=>5, link => 'product.php?id_product=5' ... and so on),
    array('id'=>5, link => 'product.php?id_product=5' ... and so on)
    // repeat once for element.
  )
);
json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the output of `json_encode($array)`, where `$array` is nested.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return an AJAX responce in JSON format - you need to add a header.

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Otherwise - you can print the array into a JS global variable.

```
<?php
echo '<script>';
echo 'var foo = ' . json_encode($array); . ';';
echo '</script>';
```